# TextView.setText is being blocked until Timer's scheduleAtFixedRate completes

Tags: android, timer

Sorry for the awkward title, I didn't know how to describe my problem much more clearly.

I have two `textviews` on the screen. One `textview` is the number of seconds left in the minute (So it will always be less than 60, when it reaches 0 it will start over at 59), and the other `textview` holds the total amount of seconds left in the timer (Which starts at a number that could be greater than 60 and counts down to 0 before halting).

I have a button that will swap the references to these `TextViews`, so that the text that held the amount of seconds left in the minute will be swapped with the text that held the total amount of seconds remaining, and vice versa. The button can be clicked multiple times so the values can be swapped back and forth as the user chooses.

What is strange is that when I am setting the text, it will update the `textviews` instantly when I am swapping from one direction to the other (from seconds in minutes to total seconds left), but the other direction will be delayed and wait until the `scheduleAtFixedRate` timer completes another iteration (ever 1000ms).

Obviously, the behaviour I want is to swap the text immediately with no delays. It only works like this in one direction, but not the other.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
String totalSecs = secondsTotal.getText().toString();
String secsSecs = seconds.getText().toString();

//switch the TextView id's
//WORKS IMMEDIATELY
if (seconds.getId() == R.id.secondsTotal){
    seconds = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.secondsLabel);
    secondsTotal = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.secondsTotal);
    seconds.setText(totalSecs);
    secondsTotal.setText(secsSecs);
}
else{ //IS DELAYED UNTIL TIMER ITERATION
    seconds = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.secondsTotal);
    secondsTotal = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.secondsLabel);
    seconds.setText(secsSecs);
    secondsTotal.setText(totalSecs);
}
```

My Timer looks like so:

```
Timer t = new Timer();

//set the schedule function
t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startCountdown(); //for seconds left in minute
                startCountdownTotal(); //for total seconds remaining
            }
        });
    }
}, 0, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

add

```
 seconds.invalidate();
 secondsTotal.invalidate();
```

after the calls when you change the values
What's probably happening is that the text values for (in minutes) is shorter than the existing text in the view so it force a layout to happen.

Comment: This has no effect. I believe the setText method also will invalidate the view anyways

Comment: ok.. you're correct. setText() will call invalidate(), but it tries to optimize out the requestLayout() call based on whether the width and/or height have changed ..